# MX record set up using Zoho mail and Linode DNS manager

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, linode

I've decided to try Zoho's email service given that it's free up to 10 users. I'm having difficulty getting my mx records to jibe correctly with Zoho. Unfortunately Zoho's documentation is over simplistic, so I'm obviously missing something simple. Here's what it says:

```
The MX Records of Zoho are:
Host Name   Address            Priority
@           mx.zohomail.com     10
@           mx2.zohomail.com    20
Choose your domain provider and follow the steps to change the MX Records to point to your domain.   
The emails to your domain will not be received in Zoho, unless you complete the change of MX Records.
```

I think there's a piece I'm missing between the Linode DNS manager and Zoho. Per Zoho instructions above there are 2 parts here: Host Name and the Address. However on the Linode DNS manager I'm given just one field for MX:  "Mail Server"  For this I simply typed in mx.zohomail.com and ommited any reference to @

I did a dig mx example.com and came up with:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.       300  IN  MX  20 mx2.zohomail.com.
example.com.       300  IN  MX  10 mx.zohomail.com.
example.com.       300  IN  MX  10 mail.example.com.
```

Ideas? I love the prospect of free hosted email to get away from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup looks fine, just remove the last MX entry (it was probably there by default):

`example.com.       300  IN  MX  10 mail.example.com.`